# Result of semantic's query sqwrl:makeBag

Tags: semantic-web, owl, swrl

I have an example about ontology with only class Person and a try to create a collection throw sqwrl:makeBag

```
Person(?p) ˚ sqwrl:makeBag(?bag, ?p) ˚ sqwrl:size(?size, ?bag) -> sqwrl:select(?size)
```

And I have 4 individuals with type Person but when I run the query result is 1. I don't know why please help me thanks so much

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The result of query is return the size of bag. The result must 4 because I have 4 individual have type person but it returns 1. I don't know why or have something wrong with the query

Comment: It might be a syntax issue, have you tried `Person(?p)˚sqwrl:makeBag(?bag, ?p)^sqwrl:size(?size, ?bag) -> sqwrl:select(?size)`